# How to create sfc package using vite for vuejs on GitHub package registry?

Tags: github, npm, github-package-registry

I want to create a monorepo of private package using `vite` (vueJS) in GitHub package registry.

Any `npm` package suggestion for it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You can use: [npm: vue-sfc-vite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-vite) or [github: @afzalsabbir/vue-sfc-vite](https://github.com/AfzalSabbir/vue-sfc-vite/pkgs/npm/vue-sfc-vite) and you can take help of [`lerna`](https://lerna.js.org/).
To create `monorepo` using lerna: **Follow the steps here: [Github NPM Package Registry > Publish](https://gist.github.com/AfzalSabbir/e3a729413ba780e12f6a8ade3f76bf16#publish)**

Comment: Great, I'll surely try it.